# How can I pass DOMDocument from VBA to C++ dll

Tags: c++, vba, domdocument

I want to pass a xml document from VBA template to a C++ dll. I prepared function in this dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall  ProcessRequest(IXMLDOMDocument* request, IXMLDOMDocument* response);

int __stdcall ProcessRequest(IXMLDOMDocument* request, IXMLDOMDocument* response)
{
    IXMLDOMElement* root = NULL;
    request->get_documentElement(&root);

    BSTR bstrVal = NULL;
    root->get_text(&bstrVal);

    ::MessageBox(NULL, bstrVal, L"lol", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

And I call it from VBA like this:

```
Public Declare Function ProcessRequest Lib "DllName" Alias "_ProcessRequest@8" (ByRef xml1 As DOMDocument, ByRef xml2 As DOMDocument) As Long

Public Sub ProcessRequestTest()
    Dim xml1 As New DOMDocument
    Dim xml2 As New DOMDocument
    Dim x As Long

    xml1.loadXML "<xml>lol</xml>"

    x = ProcessRequest(xml1, xml2)
End Sub
```

Yet, I get violation error on: request->get_documentElement(&root);
Why would that be? Is this not a proper way to pass a DOMDocument? Is there a way, or should I just pass strings, from witch dll would create xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the function as ByVal in C++ but ByRef in the VB declare statement.

To pass an interface ByRef, you need to declare it as `IXMLDOMDocument**`

E.g. you need this in C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall  ProcessRequest(IXMLDOMDocument** pprequest, IXMLDOMDocument** response);

int __stdcall ProcessRequest(IXMLDOMDocument** request, IXMLDOMDocument** ppresponse)
```